# Summing values from JSON file in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have a JSON file which looks like this:

```
[{
    "num": "37"
}, {
    "num": "79"
}, {
    "num": "21"
}, {

    "num": "12"
}, {
    "num": "90"
}]
```

I need my script to print the sum of these numbers, here is what I tried:

```
<?php 
$dati = file_get_contents('data.json');
$elementi = json_decode($dati, true);
$test = 'test';

$sum = 0;
foreach($elementi['num'] as $key=>$value)
{
   $sum+= $value;
}


?>
```

But I got the error:

> Notice: Undefined index: num in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 32
>
> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 32

I'm stuck here and I can't find a solution. Can someone please help me?

Comment: It was a typo, corrected it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should always start with a `print_r()` of the array if you are not sure of its shape and content.

```
foreach($elementi as $arr)
{
   $sum+= $arr['num'];
}
```

Comment: Yes, i made it work with your same solution 1 second before your answer! I'll accept your answer soon, thank you :)

Comment: declare $sum before using it in foreach, otherwise, you will get undefined variable notice error.

Comment: @SayedMohdAli The OP's original code already did that, so as I only suggested a mod to the loop code I did not include that in my code

Answer (score 4):

I would do

```
 $sum = array_sum(array_column($arr, 'num'));
```

But that is just me...

Result

```
239
```

[Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/75740defc465908ccbd5e08b1484e42ead43b76c)

Array column, sucks out all the values for "key" ('num' in this case) and creates an array like this:

```
   ["37", "79", ...]
```

Then Array Sum, will give you the sum of an array of numbers.

Answer (score 0):

- You can use function `array_sum`
- php version with:PHP 5 >= 5.5.0

```
$sum = array_sum(array_column($elementi, 'num'));
```